# Why do we have $Cov(X_s, \int_{s}^te^{-(t-s)}dW_u)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Let $W$ be a real Brownian motion and for $0\le s\le t$, we have $$X_t=e^{-(t-s)}X_s+\int_{s}^te^{-(t-u)}dW_u.$$

For $0\le s\le t$, we have
$$
Cov(X_s, X_t)=Cov(X_s, e^{-(t-s)}X_s+\int_{s}^te^{-(t-u)}dW_u)=e^{-(t-s)}Var(X_s).
$$

Why do we have
$Cov(X_s, \int_{s}^te^{-(t-s)}dW_u)=0$?

Comment: Do not post multiple questions simultaneoulsy.  Wait for answers and study them them before posting new question.

Comment: There's a typo in the stoc integral of X, it should be $X_t=e^{-(t-s)}X_s+\int_{s}^te^{-(t-u)}dW_u.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless mistaken $E[X_s.\int_{s}^te^{-(t-u)}dW_u|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_se^{-t}.E[\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u|\mathcal{F}_s]$ and as $\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u$ is a martingale $E[\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u|\mathcal{F}_s]=0$, summing up all this gives : $$E[X_s.e^{-t}.\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u]=E[E[X_s.e^{-t}.\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u|\mathcal{F}_s] ]=E[X_s.e^{-t}.E[\int_{s}^te^{u}dW_u|\mathcal{F}_s]]=E[X_s.e^{-t}.0]=0$$

Comment: Thanks, But that is $\int_s^t e^{-(t-u)}dW_u$.

Comment: It does'nt change the result but you're right I edited the post